# How to concatenate characters in an array in C

Tags: c, concatenation

I want to get a value (1, 2, or 3 digits of number) from a Keypad,
and want to print out the value on the console.

I have,

```
char val[i] // value from a Keypad from 1 through 120
            // so, val[i] could be one, two or three digit number.
```

What I want to do is,

```
if (val[i] == 1)
    printf("The number you got is %d", val[i]); // prints "The number you got is 1"
else if ((val[i] == 2)
    printf("The number you got is %d", val[i]); // prints "The number you got is 2"
    .
    .
else if ((val[i] == 10)
    printf("The number you got is %d", val[i]); // prints"The number you got is 10"
    .
    .
else if ((val[i] == 120)
    printf("The number you got is %d", val[i]); // prints"The number you got is 108"
else    printf("Error!");               // prints "Error!"
```

Please help me.
Thank you, in advance, for your help.

Comment: Why not simply `printf ("The number you got is %d", val[i]);` and forget the 120 `if, else if ...` -- the output is the same...

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int isNumber(char* s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == 0)
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char * a = (char*) malloc(4);
    scanf("%s",a);

    int i = atoi(a);

    if(isNumber(a) && i>= 1 && i <= 120)
    {
        printf("The number you got is %d\n", i);
    } else printf("Error!");
}
```

In my machine :

> Input : 120
>
> Output : The number you got is 120
>
> Input: 12A
>
> Output : Error!

Comment: I would advise to change the `"%s"` to `"%3s"` to avoid overflow problems. It would be also polite to `free(a)`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your great help. In fact, I used and operator (&) in if statement, for example for 12, ```if (val[0] == '1' & val[1] == '2' & val[2] == '\0',``` this also worked, but met error message after couple tries. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score -1):

You may try below code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int num;
int state;
int a,b,data[num];
string element[2];

cout<<"Enter amount data: ";
    cin>>num;
for(a=0;a<num;a++){
    cout<<"Enter state: ";
        cin>>state;

        if(state==3){
            element[0]="A";
        } else if(state==10){
            element[1]="B";
        }   
   }
```

}

Comment: You generally want to avoid answering a question tagged `[c]` with a `[c++]` answer. (though in this case you can simply change the headers to `stdio.h` and use `char[]` instead of `string` and `printf` instead of `cout` (and for C++, you really want to avoid including a blanket `using namespace std;` -- no need to pull the entire standard namespace into this example) No dings as you are a new user, but something to consider going forward.

Comment: Thank you so much. What I meant is that the values are from a 4 X 4 Keypad, '1', '2', '3', 'A', '4', '5', '6', 'B', '7', '8', '9', 'C', '0' , 'F', 'E', 'D', not from a keyboard. When I press the keypad one by one and by pressing 'E' key in the Keypad, the data will be stored into an array val[i]. Therefore val [i] could be 1, 2, or 3 digit number. The number of range is from 1 to 120. I'm sorry but, I'm not so familiar with C++ code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place an answer on SO, explain it a little bit. Maybe you will find that you are not answering the question. Edit your code, please.